# Three JS dashed line material not showing

Tags: three.js, line

I'm trying to create lines with a dashed pattern, but somehow the material isn't reflected on the line I'm creating and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong here...

I'm using code from [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_dashed.html) example, which should produce this:

[image]

When I take the following code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,0,0));

var material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({ color: 0xffaa00, dashSize: 3, gapSize: 1, linewidth: 2 });

var mesh = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
geometry.computeLineDistances();
```

http://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry

.lineDistances

An array containing distances between vertices for Line geometries. This is required for LinePieces/LineDashedMaterial to render correctly. Line distances can also be generated with computeLineDistances.

Answer (score 16):

`Geometry.computeLineDistances()` has been deprecated, so Derte Trdelnik's answer can not work now.

Use [`Line.computeLineDistances()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/Line.computeLineDistances) instead.

Comment: Pls provide some explanation of your solution without giving your opinion on other's solutions.

Comment: He was just informing us of the deprecation (three.js evolves) and that now one should use Line.computeLineDistances().

Comment: There is no such thing as computeLineDistances